# Difference between "der Berg" and "das Gebirge", is there any?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning, vocabulary

Is there any difference in meaning or usage of this two words? In case, what is it?

```
der Berg and das Gebirge
```

They both mean "mountain".

Comment: *Gebirge* is to *Berg* as *Wald* (forest) is to *Baum* (tree).

Comment: Gebirge is a chain of mountains, a mountain range like the Rocky Mountains or the Himalayas.

Comment: A decent dictionary would have helped, whether *mountains* or *mountain range* (Gebirgskette)is more appropriate, may depend on the context

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They don't mean both mountain. The [Gebirge](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=Gebirge&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) are mountains (plural), a [Berg](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=Berg&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) is a mountain.

There is also a plural of *Berg* (*Berge*), but there is a difference to *Gebirge*.
*Berge* is a list of mountains, *Gebirge* is an area with mountains.

Some examples:

- Die Alpen sind ein Gebirge.
- Die Alpen und der Himalaya sind Gebirge.
- Der [Mont Blanc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont_Blanc) ist ein Berg der Alpen.
- Der [Mont Blanc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont_Blanc) und das [Matterhorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matterhorn) sind Berge in den Alpen.
- Der Mont Blanc und der Mount Everest sind hohe Berge.

You find also some defintions in the Wikipedia article for [Gebirge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebirge)

Comment: Entirely correct. In addition, one can use "die Berge" synonym with "Gebirge", i.e.: "Wo machst du Urlaub?" - "Ich fahre ein paar Tage in die Berge."

Comment: In general, the prefix ge- is used to denotate a collection or a stack of things.

Answer (score 3):

Also, to complicate matters further, there is another meaning of *Gebirge* in the field of mining (*Bergbau*, i.e. *mountain de/construction*).  There, [*Gebirge*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gebirge#Bedeutung2) means the underground rock, especially if it has not yet been mined. This includes loose rock like sand

*berg~* seems to be a rather versatile root:

> bergen, geborgen, verbergen, Berg, Gebirge,…

Answer (score 1):

Gebirge means a range of mountains while berge means one mountain.....there is nothing very different between them only that gebirge is the range or place of mountains and berge is the mountain

Comment: This doesn’t really add anything to the accepted answer. But also, welcome to German Language Stack Exchange; feel free to take a [tour] of the site.

Answer (score -2):

*Berge* means a little number or one mountain while *Gebirge* means a mountain range directly.

Comment: Welcome to German StackExchange and thanks for your answer! However, this information has already been given in the accepted answer, so it may be deleted or downvoted by the community due to its brevity.